# Numpy package error

Tags: python, numpy

It is showing numpy package installed

[image]

and when I am running a code having the numpy package imported, it's showing an error message

[image]

Comment: apparently you installed it on a virtual environment so type activate snowflakes first and then run the program

Comment: It is still there after writing 'activate snowflakes'.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of how you're running it now? If you're using the virtual environment it should be something like: (snowflakes) C:\Program Files\...>program21.py

Answer (score 0):

install  numpy+mkl if you using python 3.5 64bit numpy-1.12.1+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64 if you using python 3.5 32 bit install numpy-1.11.3+mkl-cp35-cp35m-win32 
from this link you can find bit http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/